# When can a question/answer be counted as "rude/abusive"?

Tags: support, flags

When can a question/answer be counted as "rude/abusive"? I flagged an answer as that recently and got rejected.

So, what does the question/answer be like to be counted as "rude/abusive"?

Thanks!

Comment: it's quite hard to give a singular definition for rude/abusive that everyone agrees with. Approving/rejecting a r/a flag is subjective and depends on the reviewer in question. Could you give a link to the question you flagged so we can see what you think is wrong with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can take a look at the FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange: [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032/295232)

> ### What makes something *rude or abusive* and when should I flag it?
>
> A post should be marked as rude or abusive (formerly known as *offensive*) if it contains **hate speech, obscenities, abuse against people, or abuse of the community or system**, i.e., a clear violation of the [be-nice policy](/help/be-nice).